# How does the IntelliJ IDEA work like eclipse when mouse moves up Pop java doc

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, javadoc

[image]

Java doc in eclipse correctly displays @author

But,java doc don't show anything in IntelliJ IDEA.

Why?
[image]

Comment: Just a heads up, many people view Javadoc as unnecessary noise and arent commited to using it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug raised but still not having any updates. Please check.

[IDEA-114499](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114499)